# Running user data script on windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I've tried running a simple script:

```
<powershell> 

Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools

</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

I can't get this to install IIS. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare $true with the -IncludeManagementTools parameter.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```